# Wrapper class for mediainfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, wrapper

I made the following wrapper for the `mediainfo` command line. I did this mainly because mediainfo gives me more information than `os.stat`, specifically it gives me the `Encoded date` for .wma files, while the dates in `os.stat` don't represent the time the files were made, but rather the date the files were compressed (they were delivered to me in a compressed folder).

But is it actually a good idea to use a class for this? I needed to do this in bulk, for 20.000 files. Also it feels inefficient to let `mediainfo` format the information first and then read it again, but I'm not sure how to do that otherwise.

```
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class MediaInfo:
    """Wrapper class for the mediainfo command line tool."""

    # Define the path to the `mediainfo` command line tool.
    mediainfo = "/usr/bin/mediainfo"

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = Path(filename).resolve()
        self.info = self.readinfo()

        if not self.file.is_file():
            raise OSError(f"File not found: {file}")


    def __str__(self):
        """String representation (the same as what mediainfo shows)"""
        if hasattr(self, "info") and self.info is not None:
            return self.info.strip()

        return self.readinfo().strip()


    def infofield(self, field, postread=None):
        """Find a given field and return its value.

        If the `field` is not in the mediainfo metadata, return None.
        `postread` can be a callable to, for example, cast the returned type.
        """
        val = None
        for line in self.info.split("\n"):
            if not line.strip() or not ":" in line:
                continue
            key, val = line.strip().split(" : ")
            key = key.strip()
            val = val.strip()
            if key == field:
                break

        if postread is None:
            return val
        return postread(val)


    def readinfo(self):
        # Start the command line process
        proc = Popen([self.mediainfo, str(self.file)], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        # Catch the output
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

        if stderr:
            self.info = stderr.decode()
            raise MediaInfoException("Error in MediaInfo process", self.info)

        self.info = stdout.decode()
        return self.info


class MediaInfoException(Exception):
    """Custom exception for MediaInfo."""
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class might be too much. It all depends of how you want to use your script.

But I think you should take a look at mediainfo help. Issuing:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Audio;%Encoded_Date%" Filename
```

outputs only the encoded date value of your audio file, or an empty line if not applicable. Maybe you won't need your script anymore.